# make dynamic matrix query in mysql

Tags: mysql, matrix, dynamic

I want to make a matrix query from these data

```
name    distance
roby    10
dina    5
axel    6
john    8
```

and I make the query like this :

```
SELECT tabel1.name, tabel2.name,tabel1.distance,tabel2.distance  
FROM passenger tabel1 
LEFT JOIN passenger tabel2 ON tabel1.name != tabel2.name AND tabel1.id < tabel2.id  
WHERE tabel2.name IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY tabel1.name ASC, tabel2.name ASC
```

and the result is like this :

```
name    name    distance    distance
axel    john       6           8
dina    axel       5           6
dina    john       5           8
roby    axel       10          6
roby    dina       10          5
roby    john       10          8
```

but I want the result is like this :

```
       roby    dina    axel    john
roby    0       10      10      10
dina    5       0       6       8
axel    6       5       0       8
john    8       5       6       0
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT(
        'IF(a.distance = ''',
            distance,
            ''', 0, a.distance) AS "',
         name,'"'
     )
   ) INTO @sql
FROM your_table;




SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT a.name,' ,@sql, ' 
               FROM your_table AS a
               LEFT JOIN your_table AS b
                ON a.name=b.name GROUP BY a.name,b.name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Query is update according your desired result.
fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fc50/17)

Comment: thanks, that query execute but why i not see the result on my result?

Comment: but in fidlle link you give i can see the result.

Comment: @dimasadhipradana query is updated according to your need, so please accept the answer.

Comment: im sorry too much ask...i think it's not wrong with your code, but in my mysql ( i use xampp 1.7.3) those query is execute, but i can't see the result, i don't know why... is my xampp problem or something else? i'm still newbie

Comment: @dimasadhipradana select all script and then press run, because it is not a single statement.